# Remove full URL from Image path jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an application that stores the relative path of an image file in a DB. I need to remove any fully qualified URL from the path before I insert it into the database. I was using the following.

```
$('img', this).attr('src').replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
```

However, this still puts the / in front of the image path

I start with this `http://192.168.72.80/upload/11/img_3070.jpg`

and I want to end up with this. 
upload/11/img_3070.jpg

The URL could be an IP, domain so I have to be able to deal with both scenarios.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var url='http://192.168.72.80/upload/11/img_3070.jpg';

var img=url.toString().match(/\/\/[^\/]+\/([^\.]+)/)[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/040o8zt0/

EDIT 2:

```
var url='http://192.168.72.80/upload/11/img_3070.jpg?id=4';
var img=url.toString().match(/[^\/?#]+(?=$|[?#])/);
```

Comment: Thanks but now it's removing the .jpg from the end of the image URL I am getting this upload/AA/img_3074

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not check the result. I added a new solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get the path of the image element, assuming that the selector `$('img', this)` returns the correct element, you could avoid regular expressions because, honestly, it avoids the problems that come with edge-cases in regular expressions, and simply use a created-`<a>` element, and its attendant properties:

```
var a = document.createElement('a'),
    images = document.images;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function (img) {
    a.href = img.src;
    console.log(a.pathname);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L55rbhvv/).

Or, to use a function:

```
function retrievePathName (img) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = img.src;
    return a.pathname;
}

var images = document.images;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function (imgNode) {
    console.log(retrievePathName(imgNode));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/L55rbhvv/1/).

To use with the jQuery approach, you could:

```
var path = retrievePathName($('img', this).get(0));
```

Or:

```
var paths = $('img', this).map(function () {
    return retrievePathName(this);
}).get(); // returns an array of relative paths to the 'paths' variable
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`document.images`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.images).
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).