# images in Django project only visible when img src='/media/...' not with img src='127.0.0.1/media...'

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG_Y7lIDXPM) tutorial series on youtube and I'm near the end of the first video but have run into some difficulties.

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/justdjango/django-react-boilerplate).

Basically the admin page allows the user to create a dummy item with an image. This image is saved with a path of the server IP and the image name.  127.0.0.1/media/image.type

It successfully stores it into the media folder. But when I try to use this stored image on the client side with `{item.image}` it uses the server IP and image name. But on the client side for some reason, it doesn't grab the image file. Instead only `'/media/image.type'` seems to successfully get the file.

This seems like a problem because when the website goes live I would need to use a server IP for accessing and storing the image. Otherwise, I'd use a regex or string trim to get rid of the IP part of the image source to get it to work.

Pretty sure my media folder is set up correctly.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

My Image call inside ProductList.js

```
<Item.Group divided>
  {data.map(item => {
    return ( <Item key={item.id}>
      <Item.Image src={item.image}/>
        <Item.Content>
          <Item.Header as='a'>{item.title}</Item.Header>
            <Item.Meta>
              <span className='cinema'>{item.category}</span>
            </Item.Meta>
            <Item.Description>{item.description}</Item.Description>
            <Item.Extra>
            <Button primary floated='right' icon labelPosition="right">
               Add to Cart
               <Icon name='cart plus'/>
            </Button>
            {item.discount_price && <Label>{item.label}</Label>}
            </Item.Extra>
          </Item.Content>
        </Item>
       );
    })}
</Item.Group>
```

Printing of image details to console:

[image]

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776969/images-from-media-file-wont-get-displayed-in-django-template) stackoverflow question touches upon a similar problem, except the questioner seemed content with the path not containing the IP address in the path. I would have asked on that question, if it was not eight years old!

Comment: to grab the image from database you need to use {{item.image.url}}

Comment: {{item.image}} gives me the URL with the IP address then image name. {{item.image.url}} gives me undefined.

Comment: It's not ideal but my current solution is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005460/remove-full-url-from-image-path-jquery) `<Item.Image src={'/media/' + item.image.toString().match(/[^\/?#]+(?=$|[?#])/)[0]} /> `. I guess it's something to do with relative and absolute path of the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay but it can may help some over pepole.

you should run the server with the ip that you want the url to start with.

for exmple **don't** run as local host:

❌ `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

insted run the command like this:

✅ `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.1:8000`

## update:

after tring to deploy my react-django app via docker I noticed that this method isn't the optimal way to solve this issue.

so after a while I found that you can modify the url in the django serializer model class.

```
class PictureSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    // you can choose if you want to override the field or to add new field.
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    class Meta:
        model = {{The Model name}}
        fields = "__all__"

        def get_image_url(self, obj):
            request = self.context.get("request")
            return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)
```